# How to list available methods in a Win32.DLL

Tags: .net, winapi, dll, interop

I have a DLL file that has some helpful functions I want to call in my application. I don't have the documentation for it any longer.

How can I discover which are the functions exported by the DLL and their method signature?

Is there any utility that lists the functions and their arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows SDK used to include the *dependency walker* GUI utility that can be used to explore DLL content:

> Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules. For each module found, it lists all the functions that are exported by that module, and which of those functions are actually being called by other modules. Another view displays the minimum set of required files, along with detailed information about each file including a full path to the file, base address, version numbers, machine type, debug information, and more.

Nowadays, [it can be found here](http://dependencywalker.com/).

For method signature detail and creating inter-connection `.NET` code, look for your DLL in the [pinvoke site](http://www.pinvoke.net/). You can also try their add-in to Visual Studio 2003 and 2005.

Comment: Well dependency walker didn't give me details of arguments for the functions. That would have been helpful.

Comment: Added reference to pinvoke.net

Answer (score 5):

dumpbin /exports

([Dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446532.aspx)`[1`] being a utility in the Windows SDK)

`[1]`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446532.aspx

Edit: BTW as I see 'interop' and '.NET' in the tags, don't forget Reflector and [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).  (Neither of these help with actual Win32 DLL exports of course.)

Comment: @mezoid: Thanks muchly for the edit.  Sorry for mangling your it, but your linking seems to mangle my "edit:" block. Its obviously less that ideal.  Dont have time to figure out the correct escaping syntax right now :D