# How do I know which DLL a syscall belongs to?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, system-calls

I have a long list of all the calls a program I have does. What i need to know is which DLL each call belongs to. How would I find this out?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605389/i-want-to-know-what-functions-are-available-from-a-win32-dll

Answer (score 2):

hum... your title and your questions point to different things. syscalls mean something very specific, a call to the OS kernel (and those are *not* in dlls).

As it happens, Windows does not expose those directly, but rather exposes APIs in system DLLs that are responsible to call the syscall themselves.

So let's say you don't actually have a list of syscalls, but a list of calls. Is this list generated from a binary ? binaries actually have a list of the dlls they depend on, and a `dumpbin /imports binary.exe` will actually list exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Actually they are, all the user-mode portions of the syscalls are in ntdll.dll

Answer (score 1):

Given the executable, the easiest way would probably be `dumpbin /imports <exe_name>`. This will produce output like this:

```
KERNEL32.dll
           405020 Import Address Table
           4060FC Import Name Table
                0 time date stamp
                0 Index of first forwarder reference

             126 GetModuleHandleA
             150 GetStartupInfoA

USER32.dll
           405480 Import Address Table
           40655C Import Name Table
                0 time date stamp
                0 Index of first forwarder reference

              F0 GetClientRect
             17A InvalidateRect
              B7 EnableWindow
             291 UpdateWindow

GDI32.dll
           405000 Import Address Table
           4060DC Import Name Table
                0 time date stamp
                0 Index of first forwarder reference

              37 CreateFontIndirectA
             1AF Rectangle
              4D CreateSolidBrush
              44 CreatePen
             1C7 SelectObject
              53 DeleteObject
             14F GetObjectA
```

Depending on your executable, there's a pretty fair chance that you'll get more extraneous information. Since you already have a list of functions you care about, it should be pretty easy to filter this to get the information you need and leave out the rest.